# Sending SVG to cover background in CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

There are multiple posts on Stack Overflow about using SVGs to cover the background in html files, but there doesn't seem to be a consensus about how to handle this issue and none of the solutions have worked for me.

I have an SVG file in the exact same directory as my `index.html` and am looking for the best way to display the SVG in the background so that it is contained by the device (fits to the screen displayed)

The following does not work - the only thing that is displayed on the screen is the actual code itself:  "body { background: url('my_image.svg')}"  directly above the input button.

I have also tried with

```
  body { 

background-image: url('my_image.svg');
background-size: 100% auto;

}
```

but this also doesn't work.  Also removing the quotes doesn't help.

Here is the full HTML file - what is the workaround for displaying an SVG in the background contained in the same directory as the `index.html`?

Should I use the actual SVG parameters in the html file?

```
                                                                                                                                                                                <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <title><Test page</title>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <sytle>
  body { background: url('my_image.svg')}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="prose">
<h1>Take a photo! </h1>
  <label for="files" class="btn">Select Image</label>
  <input id="files" style="visibility:hidden;" type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <title>Test page</title>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <style>
    body {
      background-image: url(visit-us.svg);
      background-size: 100% auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="prose">
    <h1>Take a photo! </h1>
    <label for="files" class="btn">Select Image</label>
    <input id="files" style="visibility:hidden;" type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: tried that too, but the same thing happens.  Only the actual code is displayed on the screen, not the SVG

Comment: try it now. you misspelled style